# Bugs with rolly.js implementation on Astro v4 Project

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

I don't have to much experience working with Astro v4 framework, so i actually trying to work with it while i'm learning how to use it. Obviously i experimented a couple of bugs or errors but all of this i fixed successfully, although this isn't the case.

I'm trying to add the rolly.js implementation, but when the importation finally work "successfully", it come with some bugs.

in this case, looks like the rolly.js package is excluding the styles that have relation with the background, as the image background as the elements that have some styles for the background. That means the `mix-blend-mode` property, and as i mentioned it, the `background-image` property. But the entire website works good, except for that.

**This is how should looks like**
[image: expectation]

[image: box]

**This is how actually looks like**
[image: reality]

[image: box-showed]

Lastly, this is what i trying to do:

```html
<script>
   import rolly from "rolly.js";

   const r = rolly({
      view: document.querySelector(".app"),
      native: true,
      // other options
   });
   r.init();
</script>
<div class="app">
   <Cursor />
   <div data-scene>
      <slot/>
   </div>
</div>
```